# Perl script to read the content of an excel worksheet

Tags: perl

I’m totally new to Perl and I have a requirement like to create a Perl script which reads Excel worksheet contents from  my project SharePoint(Internet) and same should be sent via e-mail as a HTML content.

It would be really helpful if the code snippet is shared.

Comment: By "code snippet", you mean "complete working program", right? I'll get right on that for you!

Comment: @Matt Jacob : Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

We are here not to complete someone homework. If you want help, you have to show some effort first. If you are unable you can hire someone. :)

Here are some modules which you can use to read excel file:

- [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel)
- [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) -> To read `.xlsx` file
- [Spreadsheet::Read](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read)

See the documentation for all modules.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10569810)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10569810)

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis: This actually provide answer to the question.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Intentionally I didn't add essential part of the link. I have given reason for this in my answer. :)

Comment: @serenesat the point is: what happens if those links move or die? This answer becomes useless. That's why I reviewed it the way I did.